# Code appears to be in an infinite loop, cannot identify where

Tags: java

I am attempting to solve the follow problem, [CCC '13 J3 - From 1987 to 2013](https://dmoj.ca/problem/ccc13j3).

```
You might be surprised to know that 2013 is the first year since 1987 with distinct digits.
The years 2013, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019 each have distinct digits.
2012 does not have distinct digits, since the digit 2 is repeated.

Given a year, what is the next year with distinct digits?
```

It appears that my code (in Java) enters an infinite loop somewhere but I am unable to identify exact where and why my code does this. If I enter the input "1987", the program continues to run without outputting the next year which follows the condition above (the next year which has all different digits). How do I fix this?

Here is my code for reference.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        int yearInt = input.nextInt();
        yearInt+=1;

        input.close();

        boolean check = true;

        while(check==true){

            String yearString = Integer.toString(yearInt);

            String [] numsString = yearString.split("");
            int l = numsString.length;
            int [] nums = new int [l];

            for(int i=0; i<l;i++){
                nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(numsString[i]);
            }

            Arrays.sort(nums);

            boolean same = false;

            for(int i=0;i<l-1; i++){
                if(nums[i]==nums[i+1]){
                    same = true;
                }
            }

            if (same = false){
                check = false;
                System.out.println(yearInt);
            }
            else{
                yearInt+=1;
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix `if (same = false)`. You meant to compare values, not to assign a value.

Comment: Is that not what I currently have?

Comment: @pzaenger Ah thank you, I think you mean "==" btw!

Comment: @BiponRoy Btw., you don't need to compare a boolean value against `true` or `false` it is already a boolean value. So you can write `while(check)` and `if (!same)`.

Comment: Good style would have helped (swap the two branches of the `if` so the "true" branch is first and the condition is just `if (same)`), and so would using smaller functions. For example, by putting the digit-matching logic in a function with signature `bool hasMatchingDigit(int yearInt)` you could have a much simpler and easier-to-read loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need: `if(!same) {/*code if not same*/}`.
   `same = false` asigns `false` to `same` and returns the new value of `same`: `false`
2. you can use `break;` inside a while loop

```
while(true)
{
    if(/*is finished*/) { break; }
}
//code when finished
```

to summarize

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int yearInt = input.nextInt();
        input.close();

        while(true){

            yearInt+=1;
            String yearString = Integer.toString(yearInt);

            String [] numsString = yearString.split("");
            int l = numsString.length;
            int [] nums = new int [l];

            for(int i=0; i<l; i++){
                nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(numsString[i]);
            }

            Arrays.sort(nums);

            boolean different = true;

            for(int i=0;i<l-1; i++){
                if(nums[i]==nums[i+1]){
                    different = false;
                }
            }

            if (different){
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(yearInt);
    }
}
```